# What note is this and how many counts does this have?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

How many counts do this note get and what is the note called? I’m confused

[image]

Comment: Can you post a better picture?  Maybe take a screenshot instead of a picture of your screen.  This looks more like a quilt than sheet music.

Comment: Could you try to show an image with higher quality, but also showing at least one whole measure. A title and composer name or other reference could be helpful as well.

Comment: If you zoom out, it looks just like a triplet 8th, triplet 8th rest, and another triplet 8th.  That might be enough info for OP to find the answer

Comment: I updated the picture

Comment: @NadiaB providing a *big* and magnified image taken from a screen is *not* really helpful. On the contrary, you'll get the exact opposite. For future reference, learn how to properly get screen captures on your device/computer, or provide a smaller photo - in any case, ensure that what's displayed is *actually* visible and recognizable.

Comment: Importantly, what clef does this measure use? Treble? Bass? Alto? Tenor? A percussion clef?

Answer (score 4):

Not the clearest of pictures!   But I think it's this?  Here's a whole 4-beat bar's worth of them:

[image]

Triplet 8ths, with the middle one replaced by a rest.

'One-and-a, Two-and-a, Three-and-a, Four-and-a'  with the 'ands' missing.

Comment: This is it. The blob in between must be the blob part of the quaver rest, which surely must be apparent in a proper size picture.. +1.

Answer (score 1):

This seems pretty much like a triplet of eighths notes, where the middle one is a rest and the outer notes share the beam.

In total the length is equal to that of a quarter note.